# Is there a way to fetch html content from array of object?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I want to add click functionality to anchor tag which needs to be fetched from array of objects. Is there any way to fetch only the html content from array of object?

This is an example of sample response I get. From here I want to fetch **"faq_answer"** from each object and from each **"faq_answer"**, I want to fetch the **anchor tag** and add an onclick functionality to that **anchor tag**.

```
{
 "result_status": true,
 "data": [
   {
    "faq_id": "84",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question1",
    "faq_answer": "<p>From Sunday to Thursday, 9 am to 5.30 pm (UAE time).</p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
  {
    "faq_id": "89",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question 2",
    "faq_answer": "<p>Google. For more information visit the website <a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">www.google.com</a></p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
  {
    "faq_id": "84",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question1",
    "faq_answer": "<p>From Sunday to Thursday, 9 am to 5.30 pm (UAE time).</p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
  {
    "faq_id": "89",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question 2",
    "faq_answer": "<p>Google. For more information visit the website <a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">www.google.com</a></p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
 ]
}
```

> faq.html

This is my template file where I'm displaying it.

```html
<ion-list *ngIf="item.faq_answer && item.open" no-lines class="faq_lst" [ngClass]="{'rtl': item.language!='0', 'ltr': item.language=='0'}">
  <div>
    <p [innerHTML]="item.faq_answer | safeHtml"></p>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Fixed that :) Thank you. Do you have any idea about the solution for this ?

Comment: `.forEach()` + `.createElement()` + `.addEventListener()` - but because of the tags you've added these methods are out of the race. Please add a [mcve] with a sample in- and expected output.

Comment: This means I've to loop over my json data and for each item, I've to create an element and append an event listener function right? Oh okay, but if the json data is heavy this is not a good method right ?

Comment: Add click Handler on parent div inside which all elements are there, event bubbling will enable click on every element. By checking target you can verify which element was clicked.

Comment: @AakashGarg Hi I've added my html code too, please have a look at it and help me to change it

Comment: @VinayNarayankutty you only have paragraphs in json. where are anchor?

Comment: @VinayNarayankutty added code below.

Comment: @AakashGarg yes there is, it is in the 2'nd object , "<p>Google. For more information visit the website <a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">www.google.com</a></p>\r\n" .
Ok, I'll check the below code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML Code:-**

```
<div (click)="elementClicked($event)" id="dataContainer">
  <div *ngFor="let item of values.data" [innerHTML]="item.faq_answer | safeHtml"></div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript code :-**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import sdk from '@stackblitz/sdk';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public values = {
 "result_status": true,
 "data": [
   {
    "faq_id": "84",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question1",
    "faq_answer": "<p>From Sunday to Thursday, 9 am to 5.30 pm (UAE time).</p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
  {
    "faq_id": "89",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question 2",
    "faq_answer": "<p>Google. For more information visit the website <a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">www.google.com</a></p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
  {
    "faq_id": "84",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question1",
    "faq_answer": "<p>From Sunday to Thursday, 9 am to 5.30 pm (UAE time).</p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
  {
    "faq_id": "89",
    "language": "0",
    "faq_question": "Question 2",
    "faq_answer": "<p>Google. For more information visit the website <a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">www.google.com</a></p>\r\n",
    "display_order": "0",
    "is_active": "1"
  },
 ]
}

public elementClicked(event) {
  var elem = event.target;
  alert(elem);
  if(elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    //perform your logic
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put click event listener in your `<p>` tag

```
<ion-list *ngIf="item.faq_answer && item.open" no-lines class="faq_lst" [ngClass]="{'rtl': item.language!='0', 'ltr': item.language=='0'}">
  <div>
    <p [innerHTML]="item.faq_answer | safeHtml"
       (click)="onAnswerClicked($event)">
    </p>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

Then in your click event listener:

```
onAnswerClicked(event: any)
{
    let target: any = event.target;

    // Check if the one that is clicked is an <a> link
    if (event.target.tagName == "A")
    {
       // If you want to disable the <a> default behavior
       // event.preventDefault()

       // If you want to get the href..
       // event.target.getAttribute("href")
    }

}
```

Hope that helps